# What will happen after import hyper-v vm then join it to domain

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v

We got a hyper-v image (winserver) and want to import the out server1 (hyper-v running on it). server1  as our domain machine.

Can we join the VM to domain after import it?

Any problem like file missing or setting lost in the VM after join doamin?

Because after join domain, VM is use account from AD. It is a new account. Maybe some fils local account will not found under new account?

Answer (score 0):

If you've created an export of the VM on one host and are trying to import it on another host with a different domain that shouldn't cause a problem. The machine isn't being cloned so sysprep should not be required. If the original copy of the machine was joined to a domain you may want to put it back into a workgroup before exporting it.

Joining to a new domain will require the usual DNS functionality. If the machine has manual network configuration you may need to update the DNS server entries to be valid on the target domain.

Changing domains means, [potentially] using new domain accounts on the system. Those accounts will have their own profiles built from the default profile even if the username is the same, you may end up with:

- **.\administrator** (that is local administrator on the machine) - **C:\Users\administrator**
- **newdomain\administrator** (that is the domain administrator account in the domain) - **C:\Users\administrator.newdomain**

To access files stored in the old profiles you will likely need administrative access on the machine and can copy the files from one folder to another, there are tons of articles on this process, (generally speaking you can just copy a small subset, Desktop, Documents, Favorites, etc.)

Copying all of the users' personalization takes more work as you have to copy over the NTUSER.DAT file which contains the Hkey_Current_User hive information, (that is another topic entirely though.)